# Location of /static/ changes to /something/static/ when setting app.route(/something/<argument>)

Tags: javascript, css, flask, jinja2

Loading the route index() with `index.html` works - it extends from `base.html`. As do some other templates which do not have `<arguments>` in the route path.

However, at app.route('/channel/') I see Flask Server trying to serve statics (loaded from `base.html`) from `/channel/static/etc` instead of `/static/etc` and thus, the CSS fails to render. Whatever I put in that app.route('/here/') is where Flask tries to render statics from on that page: `/here/static/etc` and hence the CSS/JS 404s.

I've tried changing the loading of static content in `base.html` from the below:

`<link href="static/css/font-face.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">`

to

`<link href="/static/css/font-face.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">`

This hasn't fixed the issue. I eventually got a blank page with no content rendering at all. Made me think its something to do with the app.route() function.

App structure:

```
<dock>
  <bot>
  <nginx>
  <zigweb>
    <app>
        <templates>
             base.html
             etc.html
        <static>
            <css>
            <etc>
```

I'm using the Flask development server.

console on loading `channel.html`

```
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2019 13:58:08] "GET /channel/launch_logic HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2019 13:58:09] "GET /channel/static/images/icon/signally.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2019 13:58:09] "GET /channel/static/images/icon/avatar-icon.png HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

console on loading `index.html`

```
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2019 13:59:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2019 13:59:20] "GET /static/vendor/animsition/animsition.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2019 13:59:20] "GET /static/vendor/font-awesome-4.7/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2019 13:59:21] "GET /static/vendor/bootstrap-4.1/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

BASE.HTML
https://pastebin.com/9FgqE2z9

CHANNEL.HTML

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>hello</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

Routes.py (for channel())

```
@app.route('/channel/<username>')
def channel(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    return render_template('channel.html', user=user)
```

Comment: Did you try using url_for('static', 'filename') instead /static/vendor/.../style.css?

Answer (score 0):

In base.html youve specified the URL for the images as `static/images/icon/signally.png`. In this case the URL in relative to the current path, thus it becomes `/channel/static/images/icon/signally.png` as the base for the current path is `/channel/`.

You can change the image source to `src="/static/images/icon/signally.png"` and it would correctly resolve the path.

Or, which is probably more desirable, you can use `url_for('static', '<filename>')` as someone mentioned in the comments. In that case, Flask will automatically resolve the image source for you. One of the benefits is that if you have a custom static folder for a blueprint, you dont need to worry about specfying it explicitely, but you'll only need to write the relative name of the file.